# Minimal ATmega328p Ethernet Configuration

Tags: ethernet, atmega328, arduino-yun

What would be minimal schematic for ATMega328P in order to have communication over ethernet? So I'm not asking about attaching existing shields to existing Arduino board, but just for bare minimum of ATMega328P and ethernet on one board, so basically like minimal version of Arduino Yun.

Comment: Start with [the schematic of the Arduino-Ethernet](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-ethernet-schematic.pdf) and start removing things you don't need.

Comment: This is schematic of ethernet shield? I noticed that there's already ATMega328-20MU on it, so this is basically independent module?

Comment: It's the [Arduino Ethernet](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardEthernet). Its basically an Arduino Uno with Ethernet build in.